# International shipping times for Butterfly Labs ASIC hardware

Tags: asic, fpga, butterfly-labs

The [Butterfly Labs FAQ](http://www.butterflylabs.com/faq/) says they use USPS for shipping (except for Mini Rigs), and displays the options "Standard" and "Express" during the checkout process:
[image: screenshot during checkout]

However, the USPS website appears to offer "Express" shipping (1-3 business days) and "Priority" (6-10 business days) for international shipping.

I'm sure people out there have received FPGA devices internationally from BFL in the past, probably with the same international shipping options. Can anyone confirm that delivery times of BFL hardware are equivalent to the two options I found on the USPS website?

Answer (score 1):

I am in London, United Kingdom. I selected the standard shipping option, which came to $38.00 (hardware was $149.00). I made my order back in April 2013, and they shipped in October 2013. ButterflyLabs used USPS (United States Postal Service) shipping option. I could track the order via the USPS site, although it says it got to the UK, and then was held - for about a month (presume they were working out import tax on the product) and then returned to Butterfly Labs, without informing me. Butterfly labs are now ignoring any communication from me, as I  try and resolve the issue.

My advise would be to look for another option, as the issue appears to be with USPS, and if you get any issues Butterfly Labs will blank you, as they already have your money, and there is not much you can do about it.

Comment: That's strange (and frustrating) behaviour on the part of USPS, or whoever sent it back... thanks for sharing, and good luck resolving your issue!

Comment: I've heard back from BFLabs. They say they see the problem, and not sure why the postal service didn't contact me. They say they will repost the kit after they get it. don't know how long that will be though.. sounds as if they are weeks behind in emails and follow ups, so need to be (very) patient

Comment: When selling a product that needs timely delivery, I'm pretty unimpressed by the stories coming from BFL customers! It's not good enough to be weeks behind in customer service responses.

Answer (score -1):

there is no confirmation to this yet. at the time i was placing an order for a BF box, the prices where 50% lower and the standard shipping was about or less than 25$.

since the orders of that time haven't been even shipped yet, orders nowdays like yours are also not shipped and thus no user can confirm the shipping times. only someone from BF staff but one cannot believe their statements.

Comment: But this doesn't answer the question. He asked how to match their declared shipping with the USPS ones.

Comment: he asked `Can anyone confirm that delivery times of BFL hardware are equivalent to the two options I found on the USPS website` and my answer is no, nobody can confirm that nowdays.

Comment: BFL must have shipped quite a number of FPGA devices. Perhaps some of those customers were international and could share their shipping times and costs?